# Change color of pixel in entire screen

Tags: c++, winapi

I'd like to change any pixel's color by using WinAPI SetPixel() function. I wrote something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {

    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);

    if(hdc == NULL) {
        std::cout << "FAIL: GetDC";
        return 1;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "hdc = " << hdc << std::endl;

    int x = 200, y = 400;

    COLORREF result = SetPixel(
        hdc, 
        x, 
        y, 
        RGB(255, 0, 0)
    );

    if(result == -1) {
        std::cout << "FAIL: SetPixel";
        return 1;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Set color pixel: " << result << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

But, I don't see any red pixel. I think problem lays down in handle to the device, but MSDN says that for the entire screen should be NULL argument for GetDC() function.

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: I compile it with this command: "g++ main.cpp -lgdi32" and I get: "Set color pixel: 255"

Comment: I edited slightly code..

Comment: You are aware that other applications are drawing to your screen? That pixel might be set for a few milliseconds, but that's probably not long enough for your brain to perceive it - or for the monitor to actually display it.

Comment: I tried doing the SetPixel() in a loop and didn't see anything either. However a FillRect() did properly fill a rectangle. Seems like a limitation on the DC.

Comment: You cannot reliably render onto a device context for a device you do not own. The screen is shared by all windows displayed on that screen. Whatever you write to that DC is subject to being overwritten by the window occupying that area. You are going to have to investigate another solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, think about how small a single pixel is, even on standard resolution of 96 DPI. Chances of your eye seeing a single red pixel on a 1024x768 screen resolution on even a pure black or white background are very slim, even if it wasn't probably probably being redrawn by something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pixel gets overwritten with another color value by some other application. Basically whatever window occupies the pixel at `200,400` decides that pixel's color.

If you use an endless loop like this:

```
while (true) {
    COLORREF result = SetPixel(
        hdc,
        x,
        y,
        RGB(255, 0, 0)
    );

    if (result == -1) {
        std::cout << "FAIL: SetPixel";
        return 1;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Set color pixel: " << result << std::endl;
}
```

you might be able to see your pixel, depending on *when* your code updates the pixel and *when* the application under that pixel updates it.

I tried your code with an infinite loop and positioned MS Paint to the appropriate coordinate and was able to see the pixel.

Either way, what you are doing is highly unreliable as you can never know what other applications are doing with the device context. It's best to create and use a window that is owned by your application.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As soon as I close the app, or pause it in the debugger or end the loop in any other way, the pixel is set to white again by Paint.